# Suppose that you choose a letter at random from the word “statistics” ...

Tags: statistics

Suppose that you choose a letter at random from the word “statistics” and
that you continue to choose letters at random (without replacement) until you select a vowel.
Let the random variable Y represent the number of letters that you choose in order to get a vowel.

(a) Determine the probability distribution of Y .
(b) Repeat part (a) in the case that the sampling is performed with replacement

Here is my attempt at a solution [image: answer]

Can someone please guide me if this is incorrect? Thank you!

Comment: For no replacement, $\Pr(Y=2)=(7/10)(3/9)$, $\Pr(Y=3)=(7/10)(6/9)(3/8)$, $\Pr(Y=3)=(7/10)(6/9)(5/8)(3/7)$, and so on.

Comment: Oh I see. It would still infinitely continue right? So would I have to use a formula to show it?

Comment: It does not continue forever (the replacement one does). For no replacement, the last is $\Pr(Y=8)=(7/10)(6/9)(5/8)(4/7)(3/6)(2/5)(1/4)(3/3)$.

Comment: Oh sorry I misunderstood, I read that as replacement.  Can you explain to me why your answer is like that? Why you're multiplying by (6/9)and (5/8) etc. ?

Comment: Let's find $\Pr(Y=3)$. So we need consonant, consonant, vowel. Prob the first letter is a consonant is $7/10$. Given this happened, there are $6$ consonants left, and $9$ letters, so the probability the next is consonant is $6/9$. Given that, the probability the next is a vowel is $3/8$. Multiply.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! I looked a bit more at your first comment and then the clarification helped a lot too. Do you know if my answer for part (b) is correct or not? I used the formula for geometric distribution (if I recall correctly)

Comment: You are welcome. By the way, for replacement, your formula at the end looks right, but the numerical stuff before that is not. For example, $\Pr(Y=2)$ should be $(7/10)(3/10)$. For $Y=3$ it is $(7/10)^2(3/10)$.